# Change color of carousel left/right buttons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the color of the left and right buttons on my carousel. I tryed with background color, but doesnt work. How do i change it?

here is my carousel code:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/html_brand.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/css_brand.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/js_brand.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/jq_brand.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/json_brand.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/wp_brand.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <!-- Controls-->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Change color property of this selector:

```
.carousel-control {
  color: #bada55;
}
```

Comment: I see what you did there with the hex value

Answer (score 2):

Default arrows are glyphicons which is text based icons. Change their `color` property.

For example

```
.glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-right{
   color:red;
}
```

Comment: oh okay, thanks, but how can i change their color when they are inactive, because the inactive cursor looks kinda faded/transparent.

Comment: What do you mean by *inactive*?

Comment: When i hover over or click the arrow, it becomes solid #1E88E5, but if i dont its kinda faded...lighter shade of it

Comment: @mheonyae then just make it's color `#1E88E5`?

Comment: i did, .glyphicon.glyphicon-chevron-left{
   color:#1E88E5;
} but unless i hover over or click it it looks faded out

Comment: @mheonyae that's becuase it's parent (`.carousel-control`)  originally has a low opacity (`.5`) and only gets a high opacity on focus. Do `.carousel-control.right{ opacity:1 !important;}` and it'll shine.

Answer (score 1):

add following css

```
<style>
    .carousel-control.right{ opacity:1 !important;color:red;}
</style>
```